# how to "wait" to execute code until end of song in jplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I am looping through jplayer but the loop keeps going while the song is playing. How can I only get the next loop to start once the song being played is finished? This is a custom shuffle function. Here is the jplayer related javascript code - it works except I need the loop to only go to next iteration after each song play is finished:

```
var currentId = 0;
for (currentId = 0; currentId < numSongs + 1; currentId++) {
    $.ajax({
    ....      

        $(document).ready(function(){           
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({            
                ready: function () {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: currentURL
                }).jPlayer("play"); 
           $(".adder").click(function() {
            $.get("...php?id=" + currentId);
       });
    },
   swfPath: "/js",
   supplied: "mp3"
    });
}
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I don't see the connection between your code and your question. The code contains some AJAX that sets the jPlayer media, but doesn't start playback or tell it to loop. And then you ask about looping?

Comment: The loop is the For loop at the top. The jPlayer ( "play") line begins the play of song

Comment: BTW it would be great to know why the downvotes on this question. Interested in the feedback...

Comment: I think the down votes were placed because the question was very unclear until you provided more code.

Answer (score 0):

Looping like this isn't possible because the jPlayer methods return right away. If you hook into the `ended` event, you can start playing the next song there.